# The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='

Tags: visual-workflow

I am working with Flow Builder for the first time. So apologies if this an easy miss.

I created a formula to to grab the values in a Multi Picklist field on a custom object and update the Multi Select Picklist field on an associated Account Record. I built the below formula and am getting an error that I am missing a '='. The varMSPvalue is the variable I set up to retrieve the data in the custom object.

```
if(isblank({!varMSPvalue}), 
    [SN;SG;SA;Pet],  
    if(not(contains({!varMSPvalue}, [SN;SG;SA;Pet]), 
        substitute(substitute({!varMSPvalue},'[',"),']',[SN;SG;SA;Pet]),
        substitute(substitute({!varMSPvalue},'[',"),']',"))
    )
```

Comment: It looks like you may be missing some quotes in your formula. `[SN;SG;SA;Pet]` is a text string, right?

Comment: With formulas like this, it can be helpful to apply indentation to help you keep track of things. From my count, it looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis (and indenting helps make that clear). It might not be the cause of this error, but it would cause an issue at some point.

Comment: It looks like several missing ")"; for example at the end of the line with "not(contains(...)" (so it is "not(contains(...))") and within the "substitute(substitute(...)" lines.